# Клонируем проект с bitbucket

Tags: android, git, android-studio, bitbucket

При попытке склонировать расшаренный проект с bitbucket копирую ссылку проекта, и вставляю в терминал.

> Cloning into 'arubailo_fourthtask'...
>   remote: Counting objects: 451, done.
>   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (318/318), done.
>   Receid 0 (delta 0)
>   Receiving objects: 100% (451/451), 5.90 MiB | 466.00 KiB/s, done.
>   Resolving deltas: 100% (154/154), done.
>   Checking connectivity... done.

Вроде как должно было всё скопироваться. Но репозиторий Android пустой.
Зато если перехожу в Project Files то вижу что проект скопирован, но не совсем корректно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как возможно исправить подобное и запуститься.

Comment: а что такое "репозиторий андроида"?  И как Вы поняли, что оно некорректно скопировалось?

Comment: @KoVadim ну в самой AS, и даже на скрине выше самых файлов есть "Android" и "Project files". А некорректно потому что не могу запустить в таком виде проект. Тут если я правильно понимаю два проекта в одном чтоли.

Comment: Может быть там надо еще build выполнить, проект наверняка собирается, какие-нибудь модули там подгружаются? Их то в гит не добавляют.

Comment: @Mikl эм, а как выполнить этот build то? и о каких возможных модулях идёт речь?

Comment: попробуйте `>gradle build` в директории проекта. список модулей, зависимостей и всякого такого скорее всего в settings.grundle. В любом случае, вам надо установить grundle, ели он у вас не установлен.

Comment: `submodule` используются? Кстати, Android -- это сотни репозиториев. Как вы себе вообще представляете с ним работу? У него есть специальные инструменты для клонирования и т.д. Наверное, вам надо разобраться как это делает Android Studio.